# Using wget as a cron job to fetch contents of a PDF daily

Tags: cron, pdf, wget

I am wanting to fetch the contents of a PDF which is updated daily. I would like to set this as a cron job and have it fetch AND date the PDF file name (daily) so I always have a copy of each days PDF VERSION-COPY.

So:

- Cron runs each day
- Downloads PDF from server
- Copies PDF to disk at "/user/site-xxx"
- Prints PDF file name OR FOLDER NAME according to system date.

This should allow me to retain a copy of each days PDF contents, dated by folder/file name for indexing and searching.

Is this even possible with wget?  Feedback is appreciated!

Comment: Yea, I don't see this as being too hard with a little scripting. As to your question; I have a folder named DAILY where I would like to run this script from, using cron, to automatically: 1. Run Script. 2. Name downloaded file according to the days Date, NEVER overwriting the previous days VERSION.  I want the pdfs to be searchable for research purposes. Naming the PDF file names is great, OR have wget/curl instead place each days download into a FOLDER according to the days date, would be fine.

Comment: /user/site-xxx/DAILY

Answer (score 3):

Edit cron jobs with `crontab -e`. Add this command:

```
0 3 * * * /usr/bin/wget --output-file="/pathtofolder/wget.log" --output-document="/pathtofolder/Document$(date +\%Y-\%m-\%d-\%H-\%M).pdf" http://example.com/pathtopdf
```

This will run at 3:00am every day.

This config is better for fcron :

```
%daily,mail(no) * * /usr/bin/wget --output-file="/pathtofolder/wget.log" --output-document="/pathtofolder/Document$(date +\%Y-\%m-\%d-\%H-\%M).pdf" http://example.com/pathtopdf
```

Better alternative is make a script and put it in /etc/cron.daily/ and make it executable

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

wget --output-file="/pathtofolder/wget.log" --output-document="/pathtofolder/Document$(date +%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M).pdf" http://example.com/pathtopdf
```

This will make files in specified folder like "Document2019-04-24-20-36.pdf"

Comment: Why the /dev/null at the end?   So far I can not get it to work. May be the connection speed and I just have to wait...on mobile tethering.

Comment: Worked when I ran it from terminal after removing /dev/null. I have fcron, rather than cron.

Comment: I have add option to write log: `--output-file="/pathtofolder/wget.log"` so redirect to /dev/null no longer needed. If you dont want log, replace that option with `--quiet`

Comment: Answer edited, added config line for fcron

Comment: I make % escaped, also changed date format so you can sort files by name, and date-time will be sorted too.